# Feature Extraction Using Attention and then applying LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have a data having 100 features: [Partial Preview of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBTvf.png)

I want to implement Attention to extract 32 features from these 100 and feed those to LSTM as done similarly in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.11074

I want to implement the same architecture as given in the paper but am not able to formulate the code for doing it.

```
X = data.iloc[:, 1:101].values
y = data.iloc[:, 0].values


# splitting the data

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                    test_size=0.2,                                                                                                                                                             
                                                    random_state=2)

X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 1, 100)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 1, 100)

print("Training & Testing Data Shape: ", X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)


# Model

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1, 100)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=False))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))


# Compile Model

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01,
                                     beta_1=0.9,
                                     beta_2=0.999,
                                     epsilon=1e-7)

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
              optimizer=optimizer)


# Fitting the model

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    epochs=30,
                    batch_size=64,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    shuffle=True)
```

Some more details:

```
Training & Testing Data Shape:  (1890, 1, 100) (473, 1, 100) (1890,) (473,)

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 1, 128)            117248    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                20608     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 137,889
Trainable params: 137,889
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```